# Is there a Mongoose Type for "any Model"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

In Mongoose, there is a Model type that takes 2 arguments: `Model<T, QueryHelper>`. One of the arguments is required. For example `Model<User>`. How to I specify that a value should be of *any* Mongoose model? Example:

```
const helper = (model: Model) => { ... }

helper(User)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually really simple.  The type for "any Model" is

```
Model<any>
```

If you want to be more specific, you can say that it must be a Model for a type which extends `Document`

```
Model<Document>
```

If you want your `helper` to return something where the return type depends on the Model type, that's when you would use a generic.  Like for example if we want to call `model.new` and return the document, it would look like this:

```
const helper = <T extends Document>(model: Model<T>): T => { ... }
```

But if your helper doesn't care what type of Model it is using, then `Model<any>` is fine.